# When the word "want" is unstressed, is it pronounced like /wənt/ or /wʌnt/?

Tags: pronunciation

When the word "want" is unstressed, is it pronounced like /wənt/ or /wʌnt/?
https://vocaroo.com/i/s1nUhAfWsc9k

Comment: I don't think you'd often if ever encounter the schwa version (**/wənt/**) being used instead of ***want***, but you *will* hear it used in very relaxed speech as a much-reduced version of ***wouldn't***. I'm no IPA expert, but I though  /ʌ/ was the vowel sound in ***hut, but*** - which I don't connect to ***want*** at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal pronunciation is /wɒnt/ vowels do tend to be reduced when speaking quickly and approximate  /wənt/

What you have in the recording is *wanna* which can be produced as /ˈwɑn·ə, ˈwʌn·ə, ˈwɔ·nə/   Note that the stress goes on the first syllable.